# Converting a QGIS project to a PBF file

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, network

I have a QGIS project with 3 layers:

1. OpenStreetMap layer
2. Polygon representing a specified area on the map
3. Lines representing streets in that area on the map

How do I convert this project to an OSM pbf file?

I'm trying to then pass that file to [osm4routing](https://github.com/Tristramg/osm4routing2)  to process the street network and output a graph ready for routing.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/79881/converting-a-qgis-project-to-an-osm-pbf-file